# Angular 8: How to use createEmbeddedView() with context Properly

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong in this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-jzcxy3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)? I am basically trying to render an ng-template element using `createEmbeddedView()` with a context.

If you open the console in the example above you will see something like this

```
<h1> ViewContainerRef with </h1>
```

when I would expect to see something like this.

```
<h1> ViewContainerRef with test</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to call detectChanges() on the newly created view ([ref](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12243))

working example here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-4zdby3